# Match system path with awk in if statement

Tags: bash, awk, mount, regular-expression

I am trying to catch if the file system was mounted on a directory tree with:

`mount | awk '{ if ( $3 == /mnt/pxe ) print mounted }'`

But the string is not catched even though mount exists. The `mount` command output is:

`/home/olegs/infra/isos/test/archlinux-2020.02.01-x86_64.iso on /mnt/pxe type iso9660 (ro,relatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048)`

Regual expression match is also unsuccessful:

```
mount | grep pxe | awk '{ if ( $3 ~ /mnt/pxe ) print $3 }'
```

no match

```
mount | grep pxe | awk '{ if ( $3 ~ .mnt.pxe ) print $3 }'
awk: cmd. line:1: { if ( $3 ~ .mnt.pxe ) print $3 }
awk: cmd. line:1:             ^ syntax error

mount | grep pxe | awk '{ if ( $3 ~ \/mnt\/pxe ) print $3 }'
awk: cmd. line:1: { if ( $3 ~ \/mnt\/pxe ) print $3 }
awk: cmd. line:1:             ^ backslash not last character on line
awk: cmd. line:1: { if ( $3 ~ \/mnt\/pxe ) print $3 }
awk: cmd. line:1:             ^ syntax error
```

Please suggest the right syntax to match only `/mnt/pxe` path to the `$3` field.

Comment: `$3 ~ "^/mnt/pxe$"`, `$3 == "/mnt/pxe"`

Comment: You need to double quote both `"/mnt/pxe"` and `"mounted"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right, just use quotes for string comparisons:

```
mount | awk '{ if ( $3 == "/mnt/pxe" ) print "mounted" }'
```

Please note that "mounted" is also enclosed in quotes.

However, if you prefer to use regular expressions, just remember to  start and end them with a slash:

```
mount | awk '{ if ( $3 ~ /.mnt.pxe/ ) print "mounted" }'
mount | awk '{ if ( $3 ~ /\/mnt\/pxe/ ) print "mounted" }'
mount | awk '{ if ( $3 ~ /^\/mnt\/pxe$/ ) print "mounted" }' #For exact match
```